# Rails 3.1 Controller Query using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my `show` action I'd like to pass along all data that has a `user_id == current_user.id` (since I'm using the Devise gem) *AND* `params[:id]`

I created this
`@customer = Customer.where(:id => params[:id], :user_id => current_user.id)`

But when I try to pull a field, for example `@customer.company` I get the error `undefined method`company'`.  I know there is data for that field too.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base#where` returns an array of matching results. To fetch the first result, you need to run `@customer = Customer.where(...).first`